# MSVC: Invalid memcpy optimization?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, memcpy, compiler-bug

Consider the following code:

```
void MemMove8(void* dst, void* src)
{
    char tmp[8];
    memcpy(tmp, src, 8);
    memcpy(dst, tmp, 8);
}
```

MSVC (16.7.1) x86 with /O2 generates the following assembly for this function:

```
; _dst$ = ecx
; _src$ = edx
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [edx]
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx], eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [edx+4]
    mov DWORD PTR [ecx+4], eax
```

But this doesn't work (in some cases) if the input and output buffers overlap.

The generated code seems wrong to me; or is this a valid transformation and I am missing something here?

Comment: Does it have any effect to change 2nd arg. to `const void *src`? Maybe, it helps to stop the compiler being overly optimistic if it's explicitly "prohibited" to change the contents of `src`.

Comment: No, it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Yes, but that's why the function first copies the contents from `src` into the temporary buffer `tmp`. Then from `tmp` to `dst`. The temporary buffer does not overlap with either `src` or `dst`.

Comment: Are you `#include <cstring>` and `using std::memcpy;` or are you using the `::memcpy` (in the global namespace, from `<string.h>`)?  I don't have access to MSVC 16.7.1 for x86 target.

Comment: I should have posted compilable code :-) I do `#include <cstring>` and use `memcpy` from the global namespace. But it doesn't really matter all combinations result in the same assembly.

Comment: I presume switching to `std::memmove` fixes the problem?  (I wish godbolt had MSVC 16.7.1 x86.)  On my platform, `::memcpy` and `std::memcpy` are defined differently (but that's not MSVC 16.7.1).

Comment: I think you found a *bona fide* compiler bug.  Congratulations!  Can you reproduce with MSVC 19.24?  If so, file a bug report.  If not, the bug has since been fixed.

Comment: MSVC just imports the `::memcpy` function into the std namespace. So `memcpy` and `std::memcpy` are actually the same. The `MemMove8` function exists only because MSVC does not "inline" `memmove(dst, src, 8)` (calls a library function instead of generating some `mov` instructions) but it does "inline" `std::memcpy(dst, src, 8)`. It's just a performance optimization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219901/discussion-between-eljay-and-alex).

Comment: Yup, looks like a bug.  But the fact that you even need this workaround at all means it's time to find a better compiler (e.g. clang) that can inline memmove in the first place, and does the loads first before either store even when inlining memcpy, if it has enough registers:  https://godbolt.org/z/GGTcsq

Comment: Agreed. 100%. It's a _little_ bit annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1151407/incorrect-memcpy-optimization.html

This seems to have been fixed in VS 16.8.